# Code format button in editor doesn't work on iPad

Tags: bug, user-interface, editor, safari, ipad

Often on my iPad, when I tap the {} code icon to enclose text in a code block, nothing happens.

Can the Stack Overflow team remedy this?

I'm using Native iOS Safari version 15.4.1 (on an iPad Pro 11 inch).

When I select all of the following plain text to make it a code block, none of the toolbar icons respond:

> ```
> <link rel="prefetch" href="/pages/agent/statistics/">
> <link rel="prefetch" href="/pages/agent/statistics/transactions/">
> <link rel="prefetch" href="/pages/agent/consumer/">
> <link rel="prefetch" href="/pages/agent/account/">
> <link rel="prefetch" href="/pages/feedback/">
> <link rel="prefetch" href="/pages/contact/">
> <link rel="prefetch" href="/pages/agent/cancel-order/">
> <link rel="prefetch" href="/pages/agent/resources/">
> <link rel="prefetch" href="/pages/user/preferences/">
> <link rel="prefetch" href="/pages/agent/profile/">
> <link rel="prefetch" href="/pages/agent/statistics/webservices/">
> <link rel="prefetch" href="/pages/agent/statistics/webservices/log/">
> <link rel="prefetch" href="/pages/agent/statistics/webservices/error-log/">
> <link rel="prefetch" href="/pages/user/download-data/?data-type=Transactions">
> <link rel="prefetch" href="/pages/help/">
> <link rel="prefetch" href="/pages/agent/resources/">
> <link rel="prefetch" href="/pages/about/">
> ```

After a number of tries it worked.

The black iOS pop up toolbar with Copy Paste Translate Share etc. pops up when I select all the text. I think then it blocks other screen tap events.

It has been failing in tests where the length of the text to be code-blocked is longer than x characters. E.g. in the code block above and any other text about that long or longer. I just tested it with other non-code text and the buttons were all non-responsive. It did however work with shorter text.

Comment: Does this mean the `{}` button works on sometimes? Do the other buttons work and/or  behave erratically  as well? Does it happens on the same post? Please share a link to such post. When does it happen? When asking a question? In the review step? When editing an answer? When editing a question?

Comment: @rene See Edits above for some responses.

Comment: I think this happens to me, but I work around it by zooming in on the button and tapping. For some reason that works.